# QTCreator Subdirs project does not shadow build properly

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

In QTCreator 3.0.1 (using qmake/qt 5.2.1) on Windows, 32-bit w/ MinGW.

I have trouble getting subdirs projects to all build within the same shadow build directory.

I have a subdirs project with the following structure:

- Directory

  - ExternalProject

    - ExternalProject.pro
  - MySubDirsProject

    - MySubDirsProject.pro
    - MyProject

      - MyProject.pro

Where MySubDirsProject.pro reads:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    MyProject\
    ../ExternalProject
```

I have the project set to shadow-build within Directory/build-mysubdirsproject-Debug, and MyProject builds correctly within it... however, ExternalProject creates its Makefile and does all of its build within its source directory (Directory/ExternalProject).  It seems to be related to the fact that MySubDirsProject.pro reads "../ExternalProject", so it ends up not just reading the .pro within "../ExternalProject", but also ends up building within ""../ExternalProject", which, relative to the shadow-build directory, just so happens to be the source directory. How do i get the external project to build within the same shadow-build directory? Qt reference pretty explicitly says not to modify the OUT_PWD variable.